# curl_init() not defined - usual suspects not the culprit

Tags: php, iis

I am trying to run curl_init() and I am getting "not defined".

Running IIS on Windows 7, PHP 5.3.24

Checked all the common problems:

1. Extension dir is set properly.
2. cURL is being loaded.
3. Extension is showing as enabled in IIS.

Output from PHPInfo()

cURL support  enabled
cURL Information  7.29.0
Age  3
Features
AsynchDNS  Yes
Debug  No
GSS-Negotiate  Yes
IDN  No
IPv6  Yes
Largefile  Yes
NTLM  Yes
SPNEGO  Yes
SSL  Yes
SSPI  Yes
krb4  No
libz  Yes
CharConv  No
Protocols  dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host  i386-pc-win32
SSL Version  OpenSSL/0.9.8y
ZLib Version  1.2.7
libSSH Version  libssh2/1.4.2

I do not understand why it can't find the function. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you invoking said function in the same script as phpinfo?

Comment: No, I am getting the phpinfo output from the PHP Manager in IIS.

Comment: Swell. So the phpinfo output isn't actually relevant to the execution context where you want to invoke curl_init?

Comment: I think you are on to something... phpinfo() is failing too. It looks look nothing is working properly.

Comment: Oh my... I am so embarrassed I don't even want to respond, but the problem was that I was calling these functions in a javascript function by accident. So sorry for anyone who actually looked at this and wasted any brain processing time on it.